# Laravel ORM - an eloquent relationship of 3 models

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I received a DB design for a Laravel project, this is the first time I came accross a design with a table that would call an eloquent of 3 models into one 3-dimensional pivot table TBH I have no idea if this could be devised in one eloquent expression or i'll need to do some reach arounds (no pun), so I wanted to get inputs on this from you guys.

**tables / Model**

- roles / Role
- groups / Group
- users / User

**Pivot table:**

- groups_roles

**There is no User-Group/User-Role pivot in the current design as it was meshed into the following problematic table**

`groups_roles_users` which has the following columns:

- `id`
- `groups_roles_id`
- `user_id`

What I know already is that `User belongsTo roles` & `User belongsTo groups`, yet with table `groups_roles_users`:

- I doubt I would have a model for this as it's a pivot (of some sort).
- Extrapolate `groups_roles_id` via my `Group` model:

`public function groups(){return $this/*(Role)*/->belongsToMany('App\Group');}`

- extrapolate `user_id` via ??? <-this is my issue.

I would like to know how you would extrapolate `user_id`, and if another pivot table would be made, will it have to be expressed via a model so I can reach it eloquently, i.e. model `GroupRoles` that `belongsTo` users (?)

Thanks,
Erez

Comment: There's no problem with writing a quick model for your pivot table.  It makes it a lot easier to manage, even though it isn't something you'd think of as a model.

Comment: @Jeff - so a model for a pivot (first time for me), can you express that as an answer with the specs above?And does `GroupRole belongsToMany User` ? thx.

Comment: @erezt so you're saying that a group can have many roles, and the user also have many roles, and user belongsTo a group?

Comment: @Abdelmounaim - the functions I have are those: 
```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to change the design of the relationships ([Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) ) otherwise add a new model tha represent the  `groups_roles_users` table with two methods user() and rolesGroups() in it, and don't forget to specify the $table property on this model

Comment: How do roles and groups relate to each other?

Comment: @Abdelmounaim - if you can provide a detailed answer with that option that would be great.

Comment: @apokryfos Group hasMany roles

Comment: is it ever possible for a user to have roles that belong to a group a user does not belong to?